# Facebook messenger bot - speech to text

Tags: facebook-graph-api, speech-to-text, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, google-speech-api

Hi :) I built a Facebook messenger bot with webhook to my server in order to handle messages.

recently I added a cool feature - **voice recognition**.

but, I receive the Facebook audio attachment as url to **mp4 file**, none of the familiar Speech 2 text api's (Google speech, Watson etc..) support mp4 so I must convert it to FLAC and afterwards I can get the transcript.

it cost me about 6-8 seconds to 5 sec audio..

There is any Speech 2 text api which support mp4? or alternatively any way to get FLAC audio from Facebook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Lex supports up to 15 seconds of speech input to convert to a text. https://aws.amazon.com/lex/faqs/

Comment: Thanks but Amazon Lex currently support English only, and even less input audio formats..